# MySQL performance after many records?

Tags: mysql

If I had a table called "users" and in there contained 1,000,000 users, how long would it take to do a query?

Scenario 1 (1 million records)

```
SELECT * FROM "USERS" WHERE "ID" = 290000
```

Scenario 2 (10 million records)

```
UPDATE USERS SET lastname='Doe' WHERE "ID"=5525
```

Scenario 3 (100 million records)

```
SELECT * FROM "USERS" LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15
```

So basically my question is, how big can a table get before a performance hit is taken? And what times should I expect to be waiting

If a performance hit is taken, how do I manage a very large database?

Notes:

Lets say I had 64GB of RAM and that was not an issue

I also used an SSD lets say

Comment: Pro tip: If you've got a hundred million active users you can get some investment in your site and hire a DBA that can answer all these questions for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use indexes (for your queries) and partitioning, then you do not need to worry about the table size.  I mean, at some point, the index won't fit into memory and then you might have some performance issues.  But with 64 Gbytes and 100,000,000 rows, you are not there yet.

For your first two queries, you want an index on `id`, which you will get automatically if it is a primary key.

The third is just taking arbitrary rows, so an index doesn't help.

Comment: So no matter the size of the database, it will be just as quick as having 5  records?

Comment: So would I have a performance hit on scenario 3? Due to the index being an issue?

Comment: @serversideman . . . Not quite as fast as having the data on a single page, but the performance should be acceptable.  As for scenario 3, it is just fetching 5 arbitrary rows, so no index is needed.

Comment: so will I have a performance hit with scenario 3? Sorry for being an idiot, I kind of get you but I just want to be sure that is what you meant

Comment: @serversideman . . . You should not have a server hit for the third query.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I selected your answer buddy!